# ColorThief returning wrong dominant color

Tags: image, colors, uwp, background, color-thief

In my UWP app we have images that users upload and they can be pretty much any size - so when I load these into in an Image control I resize them proportionally so they fit best into our image container (which is fixed at 112w x 152h) but as some images are wider than higher what I want to is find the background color of the image so I can set the Background of the image.

So to do this I am using the [NuGet ColorThief package](https://github.com/KSemenenko/ColorThief) and the code below (taken from the sample I found there) is returning me the wrong dominant color in many cases:

```
var ct = new ColorThief();
QuantizedColor qc = await ct.GetColor(decoder);  //BitmapDecoder containing image
Windows.UI.Color c = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(qc.Color.A, qc.Color.R, qc.Color.G, qc.Color.B);     
setImageBackgroundColor(bgColour);
```

One image I tried it on was this one - now the dominant colour should clearly be black but it's returning some medium grey colour.... so is there something wrong with my code or my image or is there something else I need to do?  I'm just not finding it reliable but I know others use it without issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/KSemenenko/ColorThief/blob/a5f4519a77066c51f48e148be552062f4261528f/ColorThief.UWP/ColorThief.cs#L23) of the library, it seems it is actually averaging out the colors from the color palette of the picture

```
public async Task<QuantizedColor> GetColor(BitmapDecoder sourceImage, int quality = DefaultQuality, 
                                           bool ignoreWhite = DefaultIgnoreWhite)
{
    var palette = await GetPalette(sourceImage, 3, quality, ignoreWhite);

    var dominantColor = new QuantizedColor(new Color
    {
        A = Convert.ToByte(palette.Average(a => a.Color.A)),
        R = Convert.ToByte(palette.Average(a => a.Color.R)),
        G = Convert.ToByte(palette.Average(a => a.Color.G)),
        B = Convert.ToByte(palette.Average(a => a.Color.B))
    }, Convert.ToInt32(palette.Average(a => a.Population)));

    return dominantColor;
}
```

In this particular case, I think setting `ignoreWhite` to `true` might return the actual black color, although it seems `true` is indeed the default setting.

I recommend using the other `public` method the library provides: `GetPalette`, to see what is the actual color palette of this image. This should explain why you are getting this particular color.

```
var palette = await GetPalette(decoder);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - I have now played with this quite extensively and found the quantized colour is indeed some sort of averaged colour and of all the images I tried is mostly wrong (in terms of using as b/g colour that is) except when the image is very basic and has a very large amount of one colour - so I can't use this. I also tried taking the highest value of 'Population' from the Palette and experimenting with quality (1-10) and how many colours it retrieves and it's more reliable but it's still not ideal.... still experimenting though.

Comment: ...so for now I want to leave this unanswered to see if I can work out a reliable way to do it.  Previously I was getting the colour of each of the corner pixels and using an algrotihm to decide which colour to use (including transparent) but this also creates quite a few false positives.  I guess really there is no reliable way to do this given an image can contain so many colours and gradients not always visible to our eyes... for example, an image that looks like it has a plain white b/g actually reports the most used colour is a light cream so is still wrong for the b/g.... sigh :-(

Comment: @nzmike did you end up choosing another library, or were you able to figure out how to use colorthief?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to set quality from 5 to 10 and use GetPalette method with first color from palette.

```
QuantizedColor dominantColor = colorThief.GetPalette(tempBitmap, 5, 5, true)[0];
```